# javascript if condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What is the code for condition if - i know, what its in PHP, for demonstartion:

```
if($pass == "/secret password/") {}
```

How i can write this in javascript?

**EDIT:** Wow, many thanks for answers, i went to test it, but here is one mystake, i don't know, how i can get value of text input into variables (in ajax)

Comment: if (pass == "/secret passwrord/") {}
?

Comment: You need to learn _Javascript_.

Comment: You probably also need to hash and salt your password.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  It is unclear what you are asking.  You've mentioned Javascript, jQuery, Ajax, if and password, but we have no idea what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Don't expose passwords to JavaScript.

Comment: Actually you can write it exactly the same, only $ does not mean anything (like it does in php)

Comment: Could you give me the url of your site please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, as others have said, you should ***NEVER*** be testing the value of a password in client-side javascript because to do so requires that you have the correct value of the password embedded in the source of your web page.  That is completely hackable merely by viewing the code for the page.  It's OK to check for min length, mix of chars, etc..., but the value of a password must always be submitted to your server and checked on the server.  Only then does the password provide ANY level of security.

Then, to respond to your recent edit, to get a value from an input field, you would do the following:

HTML:

```
<input id="myField" type="text">
```

Javascript:

```
if (document.getElementById("myField").value == "whatever") {
    // value is as expected
}
```

And, lastly, please do NOT build a web page that checks a password in this way as it is very insecure.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend you to do so, "secret password" is visible for EVERYONE.

You can use the same code for PHP & javacript here.

```
if($pass == "/secret passwrord/") {}
```

Comment: The only one that recommended (rightfully) not to do it.

Comment: In our defense, the question was about how to write a conditional statement, not proper security practices. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same way.

```
if($pass == "/secret passwrord/") {}
```

Comment: This will not work as Javascript.

Comment: Sure it does. http://jsfiddle.net/SxHbp/

Comment: It works, but adding a $ in front of a variable means nothing. It's misleading to newer developers.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
if(pass === "/secret passwrord/") {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a variable by doing this:

```
var variablename = 'some value';
```

To match against it, you can do so by doing this:

```
if(variablename == 'something'){}
```